Why is cross-env failing my build on Render?
This is the last log I had from attempting to deploy on Render:
==> Cloning from https://github.com/SecRec1/Frontend
==> Checking out commit c9f35541c95df8beb355b56e75a8989e8b8de597 in branch master
==> Requesting node version 20.x
==> Using Node version 20.16.0 via /opt/render/project/src/package.json
==> Docs on specifying a Node version: https://render.com/docs/node-version
==> Using Bun version 1.1.0 (default)
==> Docs on specifying a bun version: https://render.com/docs/bun-version
==> Running build command 'npm run build'...
> Maintanence Tracker@1.0.0 build
> cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack/prod.config.js --progress  --color
sh: 1: cross-env: not found
==> Build failed 

I've tried removing it and a few random things I don't even remember anymore.
This is my env.js
const production = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

module.exports = {
  production,
  devServer: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3000
  }
};


Please do not add meta-commentary about the post to the post body. The body of the question should contain only the information relevant to solving the problem. Please also note that everyone has the right to edit posts on Stack Overflow and you cannot ask them not to. This site is a collaborative effort.
